# Probability to get the HHT sequence for the first time after n coin flip

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider a coin that has the probability $p$ to give head and $1-p$ to give tail.
I denote $H$ the event Head and $T$ the event Tail.

Let $A_n$ = "At the $n$-th flip, we get for the first time the sequence $HHT$"
and $B_n$ = "At then $n$-th flip, we get the sequence $HHT$" be two events.

**Finding a recurrence relation, determine the $\Bbb P(A_n)$.**

I cannot find this recurrence relation.

**What I tried :**
$$
A_{n+3} = B_{n+3}\cap \bigcap_{i=3}^{n+2} \overline {B_i}
$$
but it doesn't give anything interesting...
I don't understand why is it suggested to use $B_n$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well maybe you've not seen this formalism yet but here's how I would solve your problem.

Let us introduce the following Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n>0}$ : at each step we follow where we are in the word "$HHT$", that is at $n=0$ set $X_0 = 0$. If the firt coin toss is Tail, then the word $HHT$ has not begun, and $X$ stays to 0. If the first coin toss is $H$ then the word $HHT$ we just have red the first letter of the word $HHT$ and hence go to state 1.

Once in state 1, if we read $T$ then we return to state 0, because we cannot form $HHT$ by starting our word by $HT..$. If we read $H$ we go to state 2. Here is the tricky part now : once in state 2, if we read $H$ we stay in state 2, because it is possible to form $HHT$ starting from $HH$. If we read $T$ of course we go to state 3 and then we kill our particule, because we are only interested in the first time it hits 3. Formally, we are considering the following Markov Chain.

[Markov Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbNzY.png)

Now all we have to do is to remark $A_n = \{X_n = 3\} $, and to compute $\mathbb{P}_0(X_n = 3)$, which can be done by classical Markov chain arguments. More precisely, the transition matrix for the Markov chain is :
$$
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 p & 1-p & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 p & 0 & 1 - p & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & p & 1-p & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and all we want to do is to compute $P^n(0, 3)$. We could use algebraic arguments to compute $P^n$ but here we will use the Markov property.

\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{P}_0(X_n = 3) = \mathbb{P}_0(X_n = 3 | X_1 = 0) \mathbb{P}_0(X_1= 0) + \mathbb{P}_0(X_n = 3 | X_1 = 1) \mathbb{P}_0(X_1 = 1) 
\end{equation}

We denote $p_n(x, y) = \mathbb{P}_x(X_n =y)$. Then after using the Markov property at time $n=1$ this equation becomes : 
\begin{equation}
p_n(0, 3) = p_{n-1}(0,3)(1-p) + p_{n-1}(1,3)p 
\end{equation}
By similar arguments we obtain :

\begin{equation}
p_{n-1}(1,3) = p_{n-2}(0,3)(1-p) + p_{n-2}(2,3)p  \\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
p_{n-2}(2,3) = p_{n-3}(2,3)p + p_{n-3}(3,3)(1-p) \\
\end{equation}

Using $p_{n-3}(3,3) = 0$ for $n \geq 4$ (see our Markov chain description) and putting all things together we get :

$$ 
p_n(0,3) = p_{n-1}(0,3)(1-p) + p(p_{n-2}(0,3)(1-p) + p^{n-2}(1-p)),
$$

which we solve by induction.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just don't understand what the "$x$ index" in $\Bbb P_x$ stands for?

Comment: It means that we start our Markov chain from the point $x$. Actually this whole Markov chain thing is not very important as long as you understand the ideas behind the decomposition of $P_0(X_n = 3)$ : you want to know, knowing that you started from 0, what is the probability to hit 3 at time $n$. First you look at the first step : which one could have it been ? To 0 or to 1 ? Etc... Another expression for $P_x(X_n = y)$ would be $P(X_n = y | X_0 = x)$. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Yeah it is! Thank you very much